# There are $m$ distinct sets of $k$ positive integers such that no two form a fat pair, show that $m<n^{k-1}$.

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

**[ELMO 2015]** Let $m, n, k > 1$ be positive integers.  For a set $S$ of positive integers, define $S(i,j)$ for $i<j$ to be the number of elements in $S$ strictly between $i$ and $j$.  We say two sets $(X,Y)$ are a *fat* pair if $$ X(i,j)\equiv Y(i,j) \pmod{n} $$ for every $i,j \in X \cap Y$.  (In particular, if $ X \cap Y<2$ then $(X,Y)$ is fat.)

If there are $m$ distinct sets of $k$ positive integers such that no two form a fat pair, show that $m<n^{k-1}$.